# Python requests ignores proxies

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I've been trying to make a program to check for IP addresses using python but the requests module doesn't use proxies I gave to it,
Here is part of the code :

```
proxies = {"http" : "socks4://51.254.162.207:5678"}
ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org',proxies=proxies).content.decode('utf8') 
print(ip)
input("press any key to finish ...")
```

I always get my own Public IP it is also noteworthy that I am using a VPN

Thanks in advance !

Comment: i think the correct way to prove traffic goes to proxy, is to check the proxy's logs. do you have access to logs?

Comment: Your proxies dictionary only has 'http' and not 'https'

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me figure out

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a `https` entry in your dict:

```
#      HERE  ---v
proxies = {"https" : "socks4://51.254.162.207:5678"}
ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org',proxies=proxies).content.decode('utf8')
```

Don't forget to install `requests` with `socks` support:

```
# pip install requests[socks]
```